# SphinxApi and Query Seeming to Hang

Tags: php, windows-7, apache2, sphinx

When accessing Sphinx programmatically from PHP using SphinxAPI, the query command causes my web browser to think for about 30 seconds and then to fail without any log message I can find (or maybe a timeout?).  So here is my code:

```
$cl = new SphinxClient();
$cl->SetServer("localhost", 9312);
$res = $cl->query($query, "isp");
```

At this point execution stops as if some error has occurred, but not logged in `log` or `query_log` locations of my sphinx.conf file.

For my sphinx.conf file, an abbreviated portion is:

```
searchd {
    listen = 9312
    listen = 9306:mysql41
    log = {$MY_BASE}\ISP_Sphinx\log\searchd.log
    query_log = {$MY_BASE}\ISP_Sphinx\log\query.log
    read_timeout = 5
    client_timeout = 300
    max_children = 30
    pid_file = {$MY_BASE}\ISP_Sphinx\log\searchd.pid
    {$ETC, ETC, ETC}
}
```

From the DOS prompt, the search tool works as expected.

I have searchd running as a Windows Service as documented at the [SphinxSearch site](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/1.10/installing-windows.html).  I could post more of the sphinx.conf is anyone cares.  This situation does not seem to match up with any others I have seen on Google.  Sometimes it is a port issue as can be seen in other questions, but I don't think that is so here.

So what could be causing the query command to think and fail, or at least where else might errors be dumped?  I have also checked the Apache2 logs and nothing there in regards to this problem.

Comment: Is `localhost` supposed to be a variable? You have a `;` missing in your 2nd line.

Comment: Thanks for the catch.  Sorry, I can't cut and paste, that line really does have correct syntax in my code

Comment: Can you replace `localhost` by `127.0.0.1`? We had an issue with that and this is a known issue: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SphinxSearch/Troubleshooting#localhost_vs._127.0.0.1

Comment: @Mathieu, Make it an answer :)  Yeah that was the problem

Comment: Cool, will do. I experienced slow queries with this but, but no timeout, that's why I wasn't sure it was the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `localhost` in Sphinx for Windows is a know issue. Please replace `localhost` by `127.0.0.1`.

As stated in [SphinxSearch/Troubleshooting](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aSphinxSearch/Troubleshooting#localhost_vs._127.0.0.1):

> Windows Vista and Windows 7 showed problems when $wgSphinxSearch_host is maintained as localhost therefore it is recommended that instead of localhost one uses 127.0.0.1 instead

Comment: Thank you, I don't know how I would found that otherwise.  It is the solution

Answer (score 0):

try

`listen = 127.0.0.1:9312`

and update sphinx version, old version bug (src/sphinxstd.h, line 1389)